# How to code in the java language in a gradle project and make sure the code works on android

Tags: java, android, netbeans, gradle, javafx

How do I make sure that the java code I write in a gradle project will not cause errors when I install it on an android device.

I'm using the NetBeans IDE.

What I think I'm looking for is reducing the compiler to Java 6 because that's what the oldest majorly used version of android is on. (as far as I understand)

I have tried doing this to no avail since it for example still allows me to use the class Dialog while when I use this code on a tablet it has issues with the lambdas in the underlying code.

This problem arose when I wanted to make Alerts/Dialogs with Yes/No and this works perfectly in my java code but I can't find a good way to achieve this without getting exceptions on the android device.

That's why I'm looking for a long term solution where I can set the option to the lowest java currently in use on android devices.

Thanks in advance.
(If there are any problems with my question, please make me aware. This is my first question here.)

Answer (score 0):

Tested on Android Studio 0.8.6 - 2.1

Using this method you can have Java modules and Android modules in the same project and also have the ability to compile and run Java modules as stand alone Java projects.

Open your Android project in Android Studio. If you do not have one, create one.
Click File > New Module. Select Java Library and click Next.
Fill in the package name, etc and click Finish. You should now see a Java module inside your Android project.
Add your code to the Java module you've just created.
Click on the drop down to the left of the run button. Click Edit Configurations...
In the new window, click on the plus sign at the top left of the window and select Application
A new application configuration should appear, enter in the details such as your main class and classpath of your module.
Click OK.
Now if you click run, this should compile and run your Java module.

My usage case: My Android app relies on some precomputed files to function. These precomputed files are generated by some Java code. Since these two things go hand in hand, it makes the most sense to have both of these modules in the same project.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, is there any way to do this in NetBeans with gradle? Because the problem is if I switch to Android Studio there will be no way to make it work for iOS.

Comment: I will check that out and report back to you later, thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry if I'm being a nuisance, I've installed the plugin but I don't see how this helps me with what I need, I'm trying to comprehend what I need to do now. What does this plugin exactly change? Sorry again, I'm relatively new to all of this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to run your Java project on Android as well, you should have a look at the [JavaFXPorts](http://gluonhq.com/labs/javafxports/) project, that will let you run the same codebase written in pure Java/JavaFX on desktop, Android and iOS.

And if you want to use NetBeans and Gradle, the [Gluon Plugin](http://gluonhq.com/products/mobile/trynow/) for NetBeans will help you creating exactly that: a Java project based on a template (single or multiple views, with or without fxml).

The Gluon Mobile library, added as a dependency to the project, already includes a bunch of Java controls, like Dialogs, that follow Material Design guidelines.

You can use some features of Java 8: the project uses internally the retrolambdas plugin, so you can use lambdas in your code.

If you deploy to Android N, now you can also use Java 8 streams.

To get you started, you can have a look at these [samples](http://gluonhq.com/support/samples).

Comment: I'm currently already using the things you mentioned above, this is how I'm writing my java code into a gradle project. The only problem is that I want to make sure that my code works on android. Currently using dialogs & alerts in java is working on my laptop but once I put my application on an android device it gives me this: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.util.Map.getOrDefault
E/AndroidRuntime(20476):  at javafx.scene.control.ButtonBar.setButtonData(ButtonBar.java:369)
E/AndroidRuntime(20476):  at javafx.scene.control.DialogPane.createButton(DialogPane.java:771)

And so on.

Comment: This is why I wanted a more permanent solution instead of always chasing separate exceptions... Everything works on my laptop but there is always SOMETHING that goes wrong on my tablet and because of that I have to change my code again, I want to avoid this or at least let NetBeans warn me that the code I'm using cannot be used on older Android devices.